# What is association bonus and when do we get it

Tags: discussion, support

A few days ago i got +100 Association Bonus, does anybody know what is it? when do we get this? is there a rule or something?

Comment: Why are you curoius, it's a good thing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it when you join a second site on the Stack Exchange network. If you have a certain amount of rep on the main site, you get 100 free rep points on the second sites. This way you can do things like vote right away, because you've already demonstrated that you know how the system works.

Comment: But i got it here on english.stackexchange and on other stackexchange sites i don't have any reputation

Comment: I remember i had 296 points reputation and then there was a +100 reputation on my reputation history and it jumped to 396 points.

Comment: When your English.SE account is associated with the accounts you use on other SE sites, *all* those sites get the +100. If it's not the same as the linked question, then you will need to provide far more data about your linked accounts. They all look OK to me (all got the +100 bonus).